# Need proper formula to obtain correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It's my first question here. I need a formula which take the correct code at specific date. After taking correct code, excel table is using it for calculation of the correct value.

The concept is a little complicated. There is a calendar which is starting at 15.09.2021 (V3 Cell) and ending at 04.06.2022(JX3 Cell). And our codes are: ITB, OR, TBE, CBE, PO, VDR, SMF, FMF and DS. All of them are the steps of procurement process. And each of them has a specific values/coefficients like 0.1, 0.2, 0.15 etc and everyone comes true at specific date. And their locations are L2 to T2.

For example, we are taking the codes for procurement of generator at 15 September 2021:

```
=IF(V$3=$L5;$L$2;IF(V$3=$M5;$M$2;IF(V$3=$N5;$N$2;IF(V$3=$O5;$O$2;IF(V$3=$P5;$P$2;IF(V$3=$T5;$T$2;IF(V$3=$S5;$S$2;IF(V$3=$R5;$R$2;IF(V$3=$Q5;$Q$2;0)))))))))
```

L5 to T5 are the dates of procurement steps of that item.

And we are using same formula for other dates. It is working. But when, for example TBE and CBE completed at the same day, excel takes one of them (which is first). Sometimes 4-5 steps are completing at the same day. And for this situation, we can not take the true value of the item's procurement. We are calculating the progress of the procurement in that way. But as I said, it isn't working for the same dates. I tried to fix the formula by putting all possible combinations and giving them new code and coeffient:

```
=IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5;V$3=S5;V$3=T5);$U$117;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5;V$3=S5);$U$118;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5);$U$119;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5);$U$120;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5);$U$121;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5);$U$122;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5;V$3=N5);$U$123;IF(AND(V$3=L5;V$3=M5);$U$124;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5;V$3=S5;V$3=T5);$U$125;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5;V$3=S5);$U$126;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=R5);$U$127;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5);$U$128;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5);$U$129;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5);$U$130;IF(AND(V$3=M5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5);$U$131;IF(AND(V$3=R5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=S5;V$3=T5);$U$132;IF(AND(V$3=R5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5;V$3=S5);$U$133;IF(AND(V$3=R5;V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5;V$3=Q5);$U$134;IF(AND(V$3=N5;V$3=O5;V$3=P5);$U$136;IF(V$3=$L5;$L$2;IF(V$3=$M5;$M$2;IF(V$3=$N5;$N$2;IF(V$3=$O5;$O$2;IF(V$3=$P5;$P$2;IF(V$3=$T5;$T$2;IF(V$3=$S5;$S$2;IF(V$3=$R5;$R$2;IF(V$3=$Q5;$Q$2;0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

New codes are at U117 to u152.

As it can be seen, it is so rough method to use. I tried to put every possible combination but also there is a character limit and i can't write all of them too.

I hope I could explain the problem well. Maybe it can be solved by VBA too.

I'll be glad if anyone helps for practical methods. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand your objective, much less how to help.  Certainly your formulas can be simplified.  Please develop a sample data set that illustrates the problem, then **edit your question** to show that data set, along with the expected output from that data set.

Comment: Let's first see if I got it right from your description by only simplifying your formula (will not solve your problem yet, that's the next step)... can we replace it with this one (I removed absolute references for testing purpose): =OFFSET(INDEX(L5:T5;MATCH(V3;L5:T5;0));-3;0;1;1)

Comment: sorry for late answer thanks it is working yes :) it is much more practical than the old version. in my formula it is giving 0 when there is no progress. new one is giving n/a. and i take it as =IFNA(OFFSET(INDEX($L5:$T5;MATCH(V3;$L5:$T5;0));-3;0;1;1);0)

so we can think about what should we do when there is several progress in the same day. i will think too. hope we will solve with your formula :)